# How do I exclude data from a server to parse JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

This is the response I get from a server,

```
:ok

event: data
data: {"target":42,"data": `{"text":"string","numer":0,"id":1234214214,"likes":0,"isNewInstance":true,"created":1458493863596,"edited":1458493863596},"type":"create"}`
```

However, the only part of this that is JSON is

```
{"text":"string","numer":0,"id":1234214214,"likes":0,"isNewInstance":true,"created":1458493863596,"edited":1458493863596},"type":"create"}
```

So I would like to exlude

```
:ok

event: data
data:
```

from my parse each time I attempt to parse from the server?

How do I exclude this??

Comment: Not an option to do that

Comment: Are you using the Accepts `application/json` Content-Type?

Comment: No how do I do that?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't shown any code

Comment: Also, since you are not able to change the server, I assume you are using an API? Please mention that if you are.

Comment: I am Using strongloop loopbacks change stream API

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the correction of the server, until that patch you can do:

```
final String dataCorrupted = ":ok " + "event: data"
                + "data: {\"target\":42,\"data\": `{\"text\":\"string\",\"numer\":0,\"id\":1234214214,\"likes\":0,\"isNewInstance\":true,\"created\":1458493863596,\"edited\":1458493863596},\"type\":\"create\"}`";

final String data = dataCorrupted.substring(dataCorrupted.indexOf("{"), dataCorrupted.lastIndexOf("}") + 1);
System.out.println(data);
```

this will print out:

> {"target":42,"data": `{"text":"string","numer":0,"id":1234214214,"likes":0,"isNewInstance":true,"created":1458493863596,"edited":1458493863596},"type":"create"}